# Unity Container usage

Tags: wpf, prism

Prism 7.2 with Unity:
In a Module.OnInitialized (I think) I need to instantiate multiple views of same type, they must have datacontexts of same type (MyViewModel) and the constructor parameters (type string) of the view model must be specified when resolving.
How to use IContainerRegistry/IContainerProvider for this?

Answer (score 0):

> How to use IContainerRegistry/IContainerProvider for this?

Create a `MyViewModelFactory` that has a `Create(string parameter)` method returning a new instance of `MyViewModel`. Then navigate to those view models or show them directly.

View-first is the most prominent navigation mechanism, but view model-first is very viable, too, and better suited for most views but top level screens.